# Find the integral part of the product $\frac{2}{1} \cdot \frac{4}{3} \cdot \frac{6}{5} \cdot \frac{8}{7} \cdots \frac{2016}{2015}.$

Tags: calculus, number-theory

> Find the integral part of the following number $$T = \dfrac{2}{1} \cdot \dfrac{4}{3} \cdot \dfrac{6}{5} \cdot \dfrac{8}{7} \cdots \dfrac{2016}{2015}.$$

We can show that $T = 2017\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^{2017}(x)dx$, since $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^{2n+1}(x) dx = \dfrac{2}{3} \cdot \dfrac{4}{5} \cdot \dfrac{6}{7} \cdots \dfrac{2n}{2n+1},$$ but how do we calculate the integral part of $2017\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^{2017}(x)dx$?

Comment: [Stirlings approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) might be useful after rewriting it in terms of factorials. A rough application gives me something like $T \approx \sqrt{1008 \pi} \approx 56.27$ which is close to the true answer $T\approx 56.28$.

Comment: @Winther We need to find a bound for $T$.

Comment: You can use a tighter version of Stiring approximation: $n! \approx \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^n\left(1 + \frac{1}{12n}\right)$. Apply this
to $T = \frac{4^n (n!)^2}{(2n)!}$ where $n = 1008$, we get
$T \approx \sqrt{\pi n}\left(1 + \frac{1}{8n}\right)$. The error
in approximating $T$ by $\sqrt{\pi n} = \sqrt{\pi 1008} \approx 56.273$ is expected to be of the order of $\frac18\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{n}} \approx 0.007$.
This is way too small to make the integral part of $T$ differs from that of $\sqrt{\pi n}$. So the answer is $56$.

Comment: Using a spreadsheet Libreoffice Calc I approximated the logarithm, surely generating somewhat of a roundoff error but still got $e^{4.030351009}\approx56.28066279$ which is in agreement with @achillehui.

Comment: Just for the reference-value using arbitrary integer size/real precision: `prod(k=1,1008,2*k/(2*k-1))*1.0` gives 
*56.2806440115...*

Answer (score 2):

We may prove the inequality mentioned by achille hui in the comments without resorting to Stirling's approximation. For large values of $n$, we have:

$$ \frac{(2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!} = \prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{2k}\right)^{-1} \tag{1} =2\prod_{k=2}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{2k}\right)^{-1}$$
and since $\left(1-\frac{1}{2k}\right)^{2}$ is close to $\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)$, that is the term of a telescopic product,
$$ \left(\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!}\right)^2 = 4\prod_{k=2}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)^{-1} \prod_{k=2}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{(2k-1)^2}\right)\tag{2} $$
and since $\prod_{k\geq 2}\left(1-\frac{1}{(2k-1)^2}\right)=\frac{\pi}{4}$ by Wallis product,
$$ \left(\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!}\right)^2 = \pi n \prod_{k>n}\left(1+\frac{1}{4k(k-1)}\right)\tag{3} $$
where:
$$\prod_{k>n}\left(1+\frac{1}{4k(k-1)}\right)\approx \exp\sum_{k>n}\frac{1}{4k(k-1)} = \exp\left(\frac{1}{4n}\right) \tag{4}$$
by "telescopic luck" again. Here $\approx$ is actually a $\leq$. With similar arguments one may prove
$$ \exp\left(\frac{1}{8n}-\frac{1}{96n^3}\right)\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}\cdot\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!}\leq \exp\left(\frac{1}{8n}\right) \tag{5}$$
and since $\sqrt{1008\cdot \pi}=56.273\ldots$, $\color{blue}{\large 56}$ is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Although @winther and @achillehui did this the smart way and used the standard approximations I took the "battering ram" approach by first rewriting the product in the form

\begin{equation}
P=\dfrac{2^{2016}(1008!)^2}{2016!}
\end{equation}

This gave

\begin{equation}
\ln P=2016\ln(2)+\sum_{k=1}^{1008}\ln\left(\dfrac{k}{k+1008}\right)\approx4.030351009
\end{equation}

which gives $P\approx56.28066279$

Rather than write a short program to calculate the sum I used a spreadsheet but still obtained a result in agreement with approximation formulas.

Comment: @achillehui I posted my direct approach

Comment: @winther I posted my direct approach.